# Select all inputs that contain a custom attribute

Tags: extjs

I have a DataView with an XTemplate setup. The XTemplate looks like this

```
tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
        '<table>',
                    '<tpl for=".">',
                        '<tr>',
                            '<td>{task}</td>',
                            '<td>{notes}</td>',
                            '<td>{cancomplete}</td>',
                            '<td><input type="text" tsid="{timesheetitemid}" id="ts-0-{#}" style="width: 40px"  value={0} /></td>',
                            '<td><input type="text" tsid="{timesheetitemid}" id="ts-1-{#}" style="width: 40px"  value={1} /></td>',
                            '<td><input type="text" tsid="{timesheetitemid}" id="ts-2-{#}" style="width: 40px"  value={2} /></td>',
                            '<td><input type="text" tsid="{timesheetitemid}" id="ts-3-{#}" style="width: 40px"  value={3} /></td>',
                            '<td><input type="text" tsid="{timesheetitemid}" id="ts-4-{#}" style="width: 40px"  value={4} /></td>',
                            '<td><input type="text" tsid="{timesheetitemid}" id="ts-5-{#}" style="width: 40px"  value={5} /></td>',
                            '<td><input type="text" tsid="{timesheetitemid}" id="ts-6-{#}" style="width: 40px"  value={6} /></td>',
                            '<td>{sumall}</td>',
                        '</tr>',
                    '</tpl>',
        '</table>');
```

What I want to do now, is execute a Select query to select the inputs out of the DataView have a specific tsid value. I know the ExtJs "select" method uses CSS selectors but to the best of my knowledge that would require the id of the inputs to be set to the timesheetitemid value and we can't do that since IDs must be unique.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nevermind, found my answer in just reading up on CSS Selectors at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching.

My answer was just to say Ext.Select('input[tsid="' + timesheetitemid + '"]');